# Optionally modify head of sized list in shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given a `Sized` list. How can one go about optionally modifying the head if it exists?

That is, how can one define the ff:

```
def addOneToHeadIfExists[N <: Nat](l: Sized[IndexedSeq[Int], N]): Sized[IndexedSeq[Int], N] = ???
```

That is, I may call:

```
val x: Sized[IndexedSeq[Int], _3] = Sized(1, 2, 3)
addOneToHeadIfExists(x) // gives Sized(2, 2, 3)

val y: Sized[IndexedSeq[Int], _0] = Sized() // sample. doesn't actually compile
addOneToHeadIfExists(x) // gives Sized()
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary purpose of shapeless's sized types is to provide enough information about values at compile time that runtime tests for properties of this sort are unnecessary.

Verifying that a sized collection is non-empty, and hence that `head` and `tail` are well defined is very straightforward, and is one of the rare cases in shapeless where implicit evidence isn't immediately necessary. This is because we can capture the constraint that the sequence is of size greater than 0 by requiring at least one outer `Succ` type constructor in the length type argument.

This gives us,

```
def addOneToHead[N <: Nat](l: Sized[IndexedSeq[Int], Succ[N]]):
  Sized[IndexedSeq[Int], Succ[N]] = (l.head+1) +: l.tail
```

This method is defined for sized sequences with a length of `Succ[N]` for all `N` where `N` is a `Nat`, that is, for all nats greater than 0.

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> addOneToHead(Sized(1, 2, 3))
res0: shapeless.Sized[IndexedSeq[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.nat._2]] =
      Vector(2, 2, 3)

scala> addOneToHead(Sized())
<console>:16: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type
 found   : [CC[_]]shapeless.Sized[CC[Nothing],shapeless._0]
 required: shapeless.Sized[IndexedSeq[Int],shapeless.Succ[?]]
   addOneToHead(Sized())
                         ^
```

As you can see this is a type error because the compiler is unable to unify the type `_0` with `Succ[N]` for any nat type `N`.

Comment: Is there a way to have `addOneToHead(Sized())` still compile? What I'm after in `addOneToHead` is, at compile time, just to maintain the size of the list.